# flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'QueryRow' has no instance method 'call'

Tags: flutter, sqlite, android-studio

```
i am having the following error in flutter, android studio flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'QueryRow' has no instance method 'call'.
In addition to not being able to view records in the database.
```

I can't see data in listview.
I'm using the latest version of flutter and the latest version of android studio and ubuntu 18.04.
I don't get any error when registering, but when running the listview I get this error.

//   follow main code

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'MangaService.dart';
import 'Cadastra_manga.dart';
import 'db_helper/Manga_repository.dart';
import 'model/Manga.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  final _mangaService = MangaService();
  late List<Manga> _mangaList = <Manga>[];

  late Repository _repository= Repository();
  late FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;
 // _repository = Repository();
  var mangas;
  getAllUserDetails() async {
     mangas = await _mangaService.readAllUsers();
   // _mangaList = <Manga>[];
    //_repository.readData2();
   // var mangas = await _repository.readData("manga");

    mangas.forEach((manga) {
      setState(() {
        var mangaModel = manga();
        mangaModel.id = manga['id_manga'];
        mangaModel.nome = manga['nome_manga'];
        

        _mangaList.add(mangaModel);
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getAllUserDetails();
    super.initState();
  }

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    var floatingActionButton;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: /* Column( // or Row or Wrap
          children: [

            TextButton(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                  primary: Colors.white,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                  textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
              onPressed: () {
                /* Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => Manga_View(
                            user: _userList[index],
                          )))*/


              }, child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              width: 10,
              height: 10,
            ),
            ),*/
       ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, int index) {
          return Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                  mangas.MangaMap()mangaList[index].nome,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                 // const SizeBox(Height: 16)
                ),
                
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
        itemCount: _mangaList.length,
      ),
       //   ],


      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Cadastra_manga()))
              .then((data) {
            if (data != null) {
              getAllUserDetails();
              }
          });
          // Add your onPressed code here!
        },
        label: const Text('Adicionar Manga'),
        icon: const Icon(Icons.thumb_up),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      ),

      /*floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),*/
      //), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.


   // )
    );
  }
}
```

//   follow repository code

```
import 'DatabaseConnection.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

class Repository
{
  late DatabaseConnection _DatabaseConnection;
  Repository(){
    _DatabaseConnection = DatabaseConnection();
  }
  static Database? _database;
  Future<Database?> get database async {
    if (_database != null) {
      return _database;
    } else {
      _database = await _DatabaseConnection.setDatabase();
      return _database;
    }
  }

  //Insert User
  insertData(table, data) async {
    var connection = await database;
    return await connection?.insert(table, data);
  }
  //Read All Record
  readData(table) async {
    var connection = await database;
    return await connection?.query(table);
  }

  readData2() async {
    var connection = await database;
    return await connection?.rawQuery("select MAX(id_manga) from manga");
  }

  //Read a Single Record By ID
  readDataById(table, itemId) async {
    var connection = await database;
    return await connection?.query(table, where: 'id=?', whereArgs: [itemId]);
  }
  //Update User
  updateData(table, data) async {
    var connection = await database;
    return await connection
        ?.update(table, data, where: 'id=?', whereArgs: [data['id']]);
  }

  //Delete User
  deleteDataById(table, itemId) async {
    var connection = await database;
    return await connection?.rawDelete("delete from $table where id=$itemId");
  }

}
```

//  follow database connection code

```
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class DatabaseConnection {
  Future<Database> setDatabase() async {
    var directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    var path = join(directory.path, 'app_manga2');
    var database =
    await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _createDatabase);
    return database;
  }

  Future<void> _createDatabase(Database database, int version) async {
    String MangaTable= "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Manga ("+
        "id_manga INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
        "nome_manga TEXT NOT NULL," ;

    await database.execute(MangaTable);

  }
}
```

//  follow service code

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:app_manga3/db_helper/Manga_repository.dart';
import 'package:app_manga3/model/Manga.dart';

class MangaService
{
  late Repository _repository;
  MangaService(){
    _repository = Repository();
  }
  //Save User
  SaveUser(Manga manga) async{
    return await _repository.insertData('manga', manga.MangaMap());
  }
  //Read All Users
  readAllUsers() async{
    return await _repository.readData('manga');
  }
  //Edit User
  UpdateUser(Manga manga) async{
    return await _repository.updateData('users', manga.MangaMap());
  }

  deleteUser(userId) async {
    return await _repository.deleteDataById('users', userId);
  }

}
```

//  follow model code

```
class Manga {
  int? id;
  String? nome;


  MangaMap() {
    var mapping = Map<String, dynamic>();
    mapping['id_manga'] = id ?? null;
    mapping['nome_manga'] = nome!;
  

    return mapping;
  }
}

I couldn't find anything about it on the web.
```

Comment: please explain more and show source code.